# Groovy could not find matching constructor

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

Could somebody explain to me why this simple piece of code will not compile?

Node.groovy

```
class Node{

    Integer key
    String value

    Node leftNode
    Node rightNode

    Node(){}

    Node(Integer k, String v){
        this.key = k
        this.value = v
    }

}
```

BinaryTree.groovy

```
class BinaryTree{

    Node root;

    def addNode(k, v){

        def newNode = new Node(k,v)

        if(!root){
            root = newNode
        }else{
            Node currentNode = root
            Node parent

            while(true){
                parent = currentNode
                if(k < currentNode.key) {
                    currentNode = currentNode.leftNode
                    if(!currentNode){
                        parent.leftNode = newNode
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    currentNode = currentNode.rightNode
                    if(!currentNode){
                        parent.rightNode = newNode
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def inOrderTraversal(def node, def silent){
        if(node){
            inOrderTraversal(node.leftNode)
            !silent ?: println("Node ${node.dump()}")
            inOrderTraversal(node.rightNode)
        }
    }


}
```

Main.groovy

```
//Test the binaryTree Project
binaryTree = new BinaryTree();

binaryTree.addNode(45, "v1")
binaryTree.addNode(60, "v4")
binaryTree.addNode(12, "v3")
binaryTree.addNode(32, "v9")
binaryTree.addNode(415, "v7")

binaryTree.inOrderTraversal(binaryTree.root, false)
```

3 simple files. This is that I get when I press play in intellij, or when I try to run this: `groovy -cp ./src src/Main.groovy`

```
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: groovy.util.Node(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: groovy.util.Node(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)
    at BinaryTree.addNode(BinaryTree.groovy:7)
    at BinaryTree$addNode.call(Unknown Source)
    at Main.run(Main.groovy:4)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

The constructor in Node looks fine to me.

I am using Java 8 and groovy 2.4

Thanks

Comment: solved... apparently groovy has a node class....sigh..

Comment: Yes - right there in the error it tells you it - groovy.util.Node